# What happens if you buy an item from Mr. Hat at full price?

Tags: shovel-knight, shovel-knight-king-of-cards

In *Shovel Knight: King of Cards*, when you encounter Mr. Hat at his Fancy Shop, he offers to sell you items that cost 100,000 gold each. If you leave without buying anything, Mr. Hat will follow King Knight, repeatedly ask you to buy something, then challenge you to a fight when you try to leave. After you defeat him, he will move his shop and discount his items.

What happens if you save up enough gold and buy an item from Mr. Hat at full price? Does he still fight you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply put, once you meet Mr. Hat in the Void Crater then you will have to fight him no mater what because there is no way to buy the items he is offering at that time.

Even if you try to farm as much gold as you can, you won't be able to save up enough. The prices he asks for are exactly one coin above the max amount of gold you can carry - 99999 gold. Thus you are forced to leave without buying anything, triggering the battle in the process.

Therefore:

- If you visit that location, you cannot skip the battle.
- If you don't visit that location, you won't fight that battle because you will never meet Mr. Hat in the first place (Void Crater is optional and afaik if you skip it Mr. Hat will never relocate to the other two locations he later moves to)

Comment: This reminds me the bike in Pokemon Blue/Red that can't be purchased for the same reason

Comment: Couldn't you skip the fight by not going to the Void Crater?

Comment: @Stevoisiak revised the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you entered the Void Crater and left without talking to Mr. Hat.

Comment: What if you hack the game to give yourself 100k coins? Does the code actually theoretically supports this possibility?

Comment: @JonathanReez I think that it would either crash or simply do nothing, similar to what happens in Ocarina of Time if you set your time to 0:00 when racing the running man